Cancel file upload to AWS S3 bucket
I am quite new to AWS SDK C++ (on Windows) and I am facing the following problem.
I work on a library (dll) which performs the cloud communication for a user interface application.
One task of this library is to upload different files to different AWS S3 buckets, with a progress callback. This functionality is working without problems.
Now, the GUI application has implemented a Cancel button for such an upload operation and I am quite stuck on how to react to this event on my dll side.
The API between the GUI and my dll defines an upload function like this:
STD_API UploadToAWS(const Path&, ExecutionProgressCallback callback) = 0;
where the ExecutionProgressCallback is defined in the following way:
enum class ExecutionProgressCallbackReturnValue
{
    Continue = 0,  // Continue processing
    Cancel   = 1,  // Cancelled by User
    Error    = 2,  // Error occurred
    Success  = 3,  // Done processing
};

using ExecutionProgressCallback = ExecutionProgressCallbackReturnValue (*) (double progressInPercents);

The implementation of the API function inside the dll is more or less the following:
int UploadToAWS(const Path& path, ExecutionProgressCallback callback)
{
  //initialization of values ...

  auto&& [uploadResult, errorMessage] = UploadFile(bucket, awsFileKey, localFilePath,
    [&callback](const std::string& key, uint64_t uploadedBytes, uint64_t totalBytes) 
    {
      if (0 < totalBytes)
      {
    if (uploadedBytes >= totalBytes)
    {
      callback(100.);
      return;
    }
    
    double percent = double(uploadedBytes) / double(totalBytes) * 100.;
    auto executionProgressStatus = callback(percent);
    
    if (executionProgressStatus == ExecutionProgressCallbackReturnValue::Cancel)
    {
      **//how to signal the actual upload to terminate**
      return;
    }
      }
    }
    );
    
  //check result and return
}

And the actual upload is taking place in the UploadFile() function, which looks like this:
UploadFile(const std::string& bucketName, const std::string& key, const std::string& localPath, ProgressCallback progressCallback)
{
    Aws::Auth::AWSCredentials credentials;
    Aws::S3::S3ClientConfiguration clientConfig;
    std::shared_ptr<Aws::S3::S3Client> s3Client;
    std::shared_ptr<Aws::Transfer::TransferManagerConfiguration> transferConfig;
    std::shared_ptr<Aws::Utils::Threading::PooledThreadExecutor> threadExecutor;
    
    clientConfig.region = "test_region";
    clientConfig.requestTimeoutMs = 20000;

    s3Client = std::make_shared<Aws::S3::S3Client>(
        credentials,
        Aws::MakeShared<Aws::S3::S3EndpointProvider>(ALLOCATION_TAG.data()),
        clientConfig
    );

    threadExecutor = Aws::MakeShared<Aws::Utils::Threading::PooledThreadExecutor>(ALLOCATION_TAG.data(), 4);

    transferConfig = std::make_shared<Aws::Transfer::TransferManagerConfiguration>(threadExecutor.get());
    transferConfig->s3Client = s3Client;

    // Progress callback
    transferConfig->uploadProgressCallback =
        [progressCallback, key](const TransferManager*, const std::shared_ptr<const TransferHandle>& pHandle)
        {
            progressCallback(key, pHandle->GetBytesTransferred(), pHandle->GetBytesTotalSize());
        };

    auto transfer_manager = TransferManager::Create(*transferConfig);

    auto uploadHandle = transfer_manager->UploadFile(localPath, bucketName, key, "application/octet-stream", Aws::Map<Aws::String, Aws::String>());
    uploadHandle->WaitUntilFinished();

    bool success = uploadHandle->GetStatus() == TransferStatus::COMPLETED;

    if (!success)
    {
        return { false, uploadHandle->GetLastError().GetMessage() };
    }
    
    return { true, "Success" };
}

The ProgressCallback used for this function is defined as:
using ProgressCallback = std::function<void(const std::string&, uint64_t downloadedBytes, uint64_t totalBytes>
My question is how to signal the cancelation request from the API implementation to the inner function which takes care of the upload?
Also, how can I completely stop an already started AWS upload process?
I tried to call cancel on the handle from the inner ProgressCallback, but the parameter needs to be const in order to match the AWS TransferManager callback implementation.

I haven't used this, so this is my line of thought that I would look into. You problem is the wait() call; you need to get rid of that so you can wait for either the upload to finish, or the cancel button. Can you get the upload status from inside your callback? If so, I'd try a condition variable -- signal a "cancel" state from the button, or a "completed" state from the callback, and wait on the condition variable.
